# The selected field 'Id' in the subquery and the left operand field in the where expression in the outer querY

Tags: soql

I am trying to obtain all accounts names from the Accounts table that are also in the subquery that pulls organizations with Record type '012F0000001EsYbIAK' on dataloarder with SOQL

SELECT Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id From Organization WHERE RecordTypeId = '012F0000001EsYbIAK')

Answer (score 0):

Organization doesn't have Record Types on it; it is the record that defines the org you're logged in to. Some companies may rename Accounts to be called Organizations, but the actual [Organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) object never refers to an [Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm).

Most likely, you meant:

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeId = '012F0000001EsYbIAK'
```

Comment: There has been an error in the SOQL query:
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Name From Account WHERE RecordTypeId = '012F0000001EsYbIAK')
                              ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:56
The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type

Comment: Hello when I use the account table on the sub query this is the error i get

Comment: You don't need the sub query. The query provided in the answer should get you names of all Account which fall in that or have that specific record type.